# Google chrome extensions: dispatchevent in main web page

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have in my extension content script. From content script I tried dispatch event at main web page. But event didn't dispatch, nothing. For greater certainty I dispatch events in all elements =)

```js
$('*').each(function(i, entity){
    console.log(entity);
    $(entity).trigger('mouseenter');
});
```

From this [article](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), I found that extension has limited scope and no access to main page script variables.

But can I trigger elements event at main page from extension content script?

*Sorry for my bad english!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the event listener was defined in the context of the web page (but not on the content script), then the triggered `'mouseenter'` from the content will not be handled. It happens because content scripts live in an [isolated world](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment).

To achieve the correct triggering, you need to insert the JavaScript directly into the web page context. You have the following options:

**Option 1: simple with inline JavaScript**

Insert the code into a `<script></script>` tag and append it to the document:

```
var script = "$('*').each(function(i, entity){\
  console.log(entity);\
  $(entity).trigger('mouseenter');\
});";

var scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
scriptElement.innerHTML = script;

document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
```

**Option 2: Web accessible JavaScript file**

This approach is useful when the injected script has a lot of code.

Create a file in the extension root directory, for example `inject.js` with the following content:

```
$('*').each(function(i, entity){
    console.log(entity);
    $(entity).trigger('mouseenter');
});
```

Modify the `manifest.json` to make it [web accessible](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources):

```
{
  "web_accessible_resources": ["inject.js"]
}
```

And in the content script create a `<script/>` tag, referencing the `inject.js`:

```
var scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
scriptElement.setAttribute('src', chrome.runtime.getURL('inject.js'));
document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
```

Comment: I'm struggling to get this to work. I have code that works when run as a bookmarklet, but as a script tag that's added to the webpage by a content script it can log stuff to the console but my dispatchEvent calls don't do anything. 

Is there something else I'm missing?