# Simulate keydown in React aplication from contentscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm developing tiny bot for pinterest and noticed that pinterest uses React. And I have issue with message sending. I can enter message text to `<textarea>` and can simulate `input` event (to update React state), but can't simulate `keydown` event (with code `13`) to send message. React just ignores my tries.

```
let textarea = $(".reactConversationsContainer .reactNewMessageInput");
let node = textarea[0];

let event = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
event.initEvent('focus', false, false);
node.dispatchEvent(event);

event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
   code: "13",
   keyCode: 13,
   charCode: 13,
   key: 13,
   which: 13
});
node.dispatchEvent(event);
```

I will be grateful for any information on the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved this myself.

Firs of all, this library works fine for me: [simulate.js](https://github.com/airportyh/simulate.js). You can extract code that you need, lib is pretty simple.

Notice, that contentscripts can't fire page handlers, because it isolated from page (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975823/google-chrome-extensions-dispatchevent-in-main-web-page)) and you need to inject script, that will trigger event (this also described in link above).