# Triggering .dblclick() do not work (Dojo issue?)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dojo

I am creating a chrome extension where I replace a textarea by an improved version to display rich text on a website. On the old textarea, it was asked to double click and press enter to save the changes. As the website has been build in Dojo, those events were captured with :

```
<textarea rows="1" class="old_element" data-dojo-attach-point="formula" data-dojo-attach-event="ondblclick:_onDoubleClick,onkeypress:_onKeyPress,onkeydown:_onKeyDown,onmouseup:_setInputSelection,onfocus:_setInputSelection,onkeyup:_setInputSelection" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

So I am trying to trigger these 2 events when pressing enter key on the new element with the following jQuery code :

```
$('.new_element').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    console.log('enter key pressed');
    $('.old_element').dblclick();
    $('.old_element').trigger(e);
  }
});
```

The console log 'enter key pressed' but nothing happens with the events.
Any idea? Should I use the Dojo event handler?

Thanks for your help

Comment: The page runs in its own JS context and jQuery doesn't cross contexts so you either need to use jQuery of the page if your page loads its own jQuery and you're certain they'll do it forever ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34976710)) or dispatch the event manually e.g.  $('.old_element')[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true})) and the same in setTimeout(() => { ..... }, 200); P.S. an existing event object can't be retriggered at least in standard DOM so to send an Enter key you'll probably need to create a new event.

Answer (score 0):

OK so now, I am using the following code for double click. It works well.

```
$('new_element').dblclick(function(){$('old_element')[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('dblclick', {bubbles: true}));});
```

IFor keyboard event handler, I used the following code. It works well for escape key, but the dispatchEvent for Enter key is not firing the enter key as expected. Any ideas?

```
  $('new_element').keydown(function(e) {
if (e.key === "Escape") {
  $('old_element')[0].dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true, keyCode: 27}));
  return false;
} else if (e.keyCode == '13') {
    $('old_element')[0].dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true, keyCode: 13}));
    return false;
}
```

});